# Связать две таблицы в БД ( простой нубский вопрос )

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть в базе данных две таблицы, "вопросы" и "ответы" (см. скриншот). Хочу их связать, но не уверен каким образом.

[image: Структура таблиц в БД]

У меня такой вариант: указать для таблицы "вопросы" первичный ключ поле id, а вторичный поле QuestionID из таблицы "ответы".

Для таблицы "ответы", указать первичный ключ поле id, а вторичный поле correctID.

Правильно ли я решил или это ошибка?

Comment: если работает и тесты проходят - то правильно

Comment: А может ли быть вариант, что у вопроса несколько правильных ответов? Писала систему тестирования студентов 10 лет, до сих пор используем: признак правильности обычно устанавливается у ответа, а не у вопроса.

Comment: Ella Svetlaya, ну да, верно. Надо подумать над этим.

Comment: Если 1 вопрос - 1 ответ, то зачем нужны 2 таблицы? Для понта, чтобы было похоже на БД :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы всё нормально. Но в принципе можно доработать:

- если в будущем могут может оказаться несколько ответов на один вопрос, то лучше указание правильного ответа перенести из вопроса в ответ (поле `is_correct` 1 или 0, например).
- если может потребоваться чёткое упорядочивание ответов, не помешает им добавить числовое поле `order`, которое будет меняться при изменении порядка ответов и по которому будет производиться сортировка при их выходе. Можно в принципе и `id` изменять, однако это всё же идентификатор, который используется с внешними ключами, и менять его как бы нехорошо, поэтому для упорядочивания лучше ещё поле добавить.
- Я как-то не наблюдал CamelCase в названиях полей, вроде бы их везде пишут в snake_case: `category_id`, `question_text`, `answer_text`, `question_id`.